# Angular.js and Oauth 1.0 integration

Tags: angularjs, oauth, oauth-1.0a

Need help in using Angular.js with OAuth 1.0. I have checked that Oauth.io does not support the provider for Quickbooks api and Satellizer.js is also outdated as per the github spec.

Any other code/js I can use for this integartion?

Comment: Try to use **hello.js**.

Comment: But it's more on Oauth 2.0.